# How to make an application compatible in all Android phones?

Tags: android

Pls help me to solve my issue.. In most of my application the Ui design is not compatible for all Android devices.. ie..all the widgets are not aligning in proper order in all phones.. i want to develop an application which should fit all phone size and resolution ( large phones, normal ones and in small ones) ..pls resolve this issue...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That may not be possible. However you can look at these links and learn how to provide different images(pixels and density), layouts and further on. It may not be possible to make a userinterface on a low level density screen the same way as a high density screen and then you can target different layouts to different phones e.g.

[Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

[Application Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check the android developer site, mainly the following
1 . [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
2 . [User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html)